# Find the solution of differential equation given below

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\left(\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}-1\right)^2*\left(\frac{\mathrm d^2y}{\mathrm dx^2}
+1\right)^2*y = \sin^2(x/2)+e^x+x$$

I can't even think how to proceed

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I don't know why anybody would want to think about it. Tell us, please!

Comment: from where does this equation come?

Comment: This was given in my exam so I don’t know where it has come from.